# What's the longest "‫אמר ר׳ X אמר ר׳ Y‬" in the Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli

What's the longest "‫אמר ר׳ X אמר ר׳ Y‬" in the Talmud? For example [Kiddushin 39](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.39a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ואינהו כמאן סברוה? כי הא דתניא:‏
> רבי אלעזר בר׳ יוסי אומר משום
> ר׳ יוסי בן דורמסקה שאמר משום
> רבי יוסי הגלילי שאמר משום
> רבי יוחנן בן נורי שאמר משום
> ר׳ אליעזר הגדול
> אין ערלה בח״ל.‏

Comment: Maybe Avot 1:1?  (8^D

Comment: This sounds like a "riddle" question.

Comment: Does ואמרי לה X count?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Go ahead, everything counts.

Comment: VTC as it doesn't meet the threshold of https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5274/. What "desire to understand and/or practice Judaism" motivates this question? Why should I care what the longest citation is?

Answer (score 3):

[Bava Kama 80b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.80b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?

> (חב"ד בי"ח בח"ן סימן)
> אמר רבי אחא בר פפא משום רבי אבא בר פפא משום רבי אדא בר פפא
> ואמרי לה אמר ר' אבא בר פפא משום רבי חייא בר פפא משום רבי אחא בר פפא
> ואמרי לה אמר ר' אבא בר פפא משום רבי אחא בר פפא משום רבי חנינא בר פפא

> § The Gemara provides a mnemonic device for the distinguishing letters in the various names of the sons of Rav Pappa in the ensuing list: Ḥet beit dalet, beit yod ḥet, beit ḥet nun. Rabbi Aḥa bar Pappa says the following three statements in the name of Rabbi Abba bar Pappa, who said them in the name of Rabbi Adda bar Pappa. And some say Rabbi Abba bar Pappa says them in the name of Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Pappa, who said them in the name of Rabbi Aḥa bar Pappa. And some say Rabbi Abba bar Pappa says them in the name of Rabbi Aḥa bar Pappa, who said them in the name of Rabbi Ḥanina bar Pappa.

Comment: Hm, all those are brothers? the sons of R' Acha? What a family?\

Comment: This looks more like a chain of three in three different versions

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the longest, but this one in Makos 16a has six consecutive names vs. five in the one from kiddushin 39.

סבר לה כי הא דאמר רב אידי בר אבין

אמר רב עמרם

א"ר יצחק

א"ר יוחנן

ר' יהודה אומר

משום רבי יוסי הגלילי